# fatal error: Cannot index empty buffer

Tags: swift, core-data

I declare a global variable _dataArray:

```
    var _dataArray : Array<AnyObject> = Array();
```

And then define a function:

```
    func fetchCoreData(userName: String){
    var context : NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "GoodModel")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "uid = %@",_userUid )
    let _dataArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
    if(_dataArray.count == 0){
        println("We need to parse JSON")
        self.parseJSON()
    }else{
        println("Display from CoreData, we do not need to parse JSON!")
        println("_dataArray.count:%d",_dataArray.count)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

From console, I can see that there are 20 objects in this _dataArray.
But in the following function, the count of _dataArray is 0. Why?????????

```
@IBAction func endorseButton(sender: AnyObject, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    println(_dataArray.count)
    let touches = event.allTouches()
    let touch: AnyObject? = touches?.anyObject()
    let currentTouchPosition = touch?.locationInView(self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(currentTouchPosition!)?
    if let ip = indexPath {
        var data:NSManagedObject = _dataArray[ip.row] as NSManagedObject
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
let _dataArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
```

you declare **local** `_dataArray`.

You should just omit `let`:

```
_dataArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
```